# Setting up XDebug on MAMP PRO with PHPStorm and Virtual Hosts

Tags: xdebug, mamp, phpstorm

I'm new to debugging and finally found some time to play with it.
But I can't get the debugger to work in PHPStorm (2.1).

I'm on a Mac (Snow Leopard) and using MAMP PRO (2.0.1).
XDebug is installed (default MAMP - 2.1.0) and active.

One of the tutorials I've followed is this one:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/02/zero-configuration-debugging-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm-2-0/

And I used this tool for generating bookmarks:
http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/

In PHPStorm I click on the "Start Listen PHP debug connections" button and in the web browser I use the link "Start debugger". Then I refresh the webpage and expect something to happen in PHPStorm. But nothing happens.

Something should happen, right?

I think it probably has something to do with the virtual hosts (created in MAMP PRO) I'm using. When I'm working on a project I'm using URLS like dev.companyname.com

Can it run with different virtual hosts or do I have to use 'localhost'?
How can I get this thing to work?

Comment: Verify that xdebug works by enabling logging per http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log. Check the log to see if the connection to PhpStorm was successful. If it was, double check that you have a breakpoint set or enable an option to stop on the first line. If it doesn't help, provide your php.ini, xdebug log, phpinfo() output.

Answer (score 13):

I was having the same issue getting XDebug to work with MAMP Pro and PHPStorm but I finally figured it out.  Here is what I did:

1. Edit the `php.ini` file by launching MAMP and then going to File->Edit Template->PHP->your PHP version and add:

   `[xdebug]
   zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"

   xdebug.remote_enable=1`
2. Add bookmarklets for `Start debugger`, `Stop debugger`, and `Debug this page` from this [bookmarklet generator](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/)
3. Set a break point in PHPStorm that you want to trigger
4. Click the `Start debugger` bookmarklet
5. In PHPStorm, click on the `Start Listen PHP debug connections` icon
6. Load the page that will trigger the breakpoint and that should do it

For details, here is the Jetbrains [tutorial post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/02/zero-configuration-debugging-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm-2-0/).

Comment: And now I realize how much I've struggled sor far for debugging php code. Thanks this definitely helped !

Comment: Don't forget that you may have to restart the server after editing the `php.ini` file before the changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers out there for old versions.  Very simple with Mamp 2.2 and PHPStorm 7.1 (OSX 10.9)

**MAMP:**

Edit the PHP.ini for the version you are using through MAMP to enable XDebug, just as Allen describes, removing the ';' in front of the zend_extension and add xdebug.remote_enable=1

**PHP Storm:**

1. Run->Edit Configurations
2. Add a new PHP Web Application
3. Configure a new Server, host is 'localhost' and port is '8888', and set the start URL (/myapp)

That's it, hit debug and you are good to go, that easy.

Comment: Why port is 8888, where i can find my port?